# Eliminate and reduce overlapping data ranges using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a dataset in SQL Server Management Studio. The data looks like the following. i have a identifier for each people `userID`, `date` of the record, start time`startime` and finish time `endtime`.

```
UserID   date           startime    endtime
1        20110203       09:30       09:35
1        20110203       09:31       09:38
1        20110203       10:03       10:05
1        20110203      10:04:00    10:35:00
2        20110203       11:02       11:05
```

For each people, i want check if there is any overlapping time. If there is, I want to keep the smallest `startime` and largest `endtime`.  if no overlapping time, I keep the original data. In addition, I want to calculate the duration of `maxi endtime` and `smallest startime`.

The result I want should looks like the following. Can anyone teach me how to code this please.

```
UserID   date           startime    endtime    diff 
1        20110203       09:30       09:38       00:08
1        20110203       10:03       10:35       00:02
2        20110203       11:02       11:05       00:03
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Search for Itzik Ben-Gan interval packing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SELECT with CTE needs to recursively merge undetermined number of rows. In that case I would prefer safe CURSOR based solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  UserId int,
  [Date] date,
  StartTime time,
  EndTime time
);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '2011-02-03', '09:30:00', '09:35:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '09:31:00', '09:38:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '09:36:00', '09:41:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '09:40:00', '09:45:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '09:42:00', '09:43:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '10:03:00', '10:05:00'),
(2, '2011-02-03', '11:02:00', '11:05:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '12:00:00', '12:05:00'),
(1, '2011-02-03', '12:04:00', '12:06:00');

------------------
DECLARE @result TABLE
(
  UserId int,
  [Date] date,
  StartTime time,
  EndTime time
)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT UserId, [Date], StartTime, EndTime
    FROM @t
    ORDER BY UserId, [Date], StartTime;

DECLARE @UserId int
DECLARE @Date date
DECLARE @StartTime time
DECLARE @EndTime time

DECLARE @LastUserId int
DECLARE @LastDate date
DECLARE @LastStartTime time
DECLARE @LastEndTime time

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @UserId, @Date, @StartTime, @EndTime
SET @LastUserId = @UserId
SET @LastDate = @Date
SET @LastStartTime = @StartTime
SET @LastEndTime = @EndTime
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @UserId = @LastUserId AND @Date = @LastDate AND @StartTime <= @LastEndTime
    SET @LastEndTime = CASE WHEN @LastEndTime > @EndTime THEN @LastEndTime ELSE @EndTime END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT @result(UserId, [Date], StartTime, EndTime) VALUES (@LastUserId, @LastDate, @LastStartTime, @LastEndTime)
    SET @LastUserId = @UserId
    SET @LastDate = @Date
    SET @LastStartTime = @StartTime
    SET @LastEndTime = @EndTime
  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @UserId, @Date, @StartTime, @EndTime
END
INSERT @result(UserId, [Date], StartTime, EndTime) VALUES (@LastUserId, @LastDate, @LastStartTime, @LastEndTime)

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT UserId,
       [Date],
       StartTime,
       EndTime,
       CAST(DATEADD(second,DATEDIFF(second,StartTime,EndTime),'2000-01-01') AS time) Diff
       FROM @result
```

which returns

```
1   2011-02-03  09:30:00.0000000    09:45:00.0000000    00:15:00.0000000
1   2011-02-03  10:03:00.0000000    10:05:00.0000000    00:02:00.0000000
1   2011-02-03  12:00:00.0000000    12:06:00.0000000    00:06:00.0000000
2   2011-02-03  11:02:00.0000000    11:05:00.0000000    00:03:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Following a redesigned Version of my previous cte Approach. However, it will still have Problems if there are multiple records for the same user with identical start time... didn't have time to fix that one, but as far as I understood this is not possible in the described process!?

```
--
-- This part is temporary and has to be replaced by your tables
-- There several more records included now
-- There is still a glitch if the starttime is identical for two records - but as far as I understood, this is not possible in the described case?
--
declare @t table (userid int, date int, starttime time, endtime time);
insert into @t values (1, 20110203, '09:30:00', '09:35:00'), (1, 20110203, '09:31:00', '09:38:00'), (1, 20110203, '09:36:00', '09:41:00'), (1, 20110203, '10:03:00', '10:05:00'),(1, 20110203, '10:04:00', '10:35:00'),
                      (2, 20110203, '11:02:00', '11:05:00'), (2, 20110203, '11:03:00', '11:20:00'), (2, 20110203, '11:04:00', '11:35:00'), (2, 20110203, '13:02:00', '13:05:00'), (2, 20110203, '13:04:00', '13:15:00');

--
-- First cte: selects all start and endtimes and their - if existing - "overlaps"; recursive cte
--
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 1 lvl, a.userid
         ,CASE WHEN a.starttime <= ISNULL(b.starttime, a.starttime) THEN a.starttime ELSE b.starttime END AS starttime
         ,CASE WHEN a.endtime >= ISNULL(b.endtime, a.endtime) THEN a.endtime ELSE b.endtime END AS endtime
    FROM @t as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @t AS b ON b.userid = a.userid
                                AND b.starttime < a.starttime
                                AND b.endtime > a.starttime
  UNION ALL
  select a.lvl+1, a.userid
    ,CASE WHEN a.starttime <= ISNULL(b.starttime, a.starttime) THEN a.starttime ELSE b.starttime END AS xStart
    ,CASE WHEN a.endtime >= ISNULL(b.endtime, a.endtime) THEN a.endtime ELSE b.endtime END AS xEnd
    from cte as a
    INNER JOIN @t AS b ON b.userid = a.userid
                                AND b.starttime < a.starttime
                                AND b.endtime > a.starttime
),
--
-- Second cte: get the max. lvl result per user from the recursive cte
--
cteUserMaxLvl AS (
  SELECT userid, max(lvl) AS MaxLvl
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY userid
),
--
-- third cte: get the rows matching the max.lvl; their timespan should cover the desired min. start and max. end
--
cteNoMoreOverlap AS(
  SELECT a.userid, starttime, endtime
    FROM cte AS a
    JOIN cteUserMaxLvl AS b ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.lvl = b.MaxLvl
)
--
-- Select the rows from the "No more overlap" cte
--
SELECT userid, starttime, endtime
  FROM cteNoMoreOverlap
UNION ALL
--
-- And finally select all rows, which are not covered by the previously selected timespan
--
SELECT a.userid, min(a.starttime) AS starttime, max(a.endtime) AS endtime
  FROM cte AS a
  JOIN cteNoMoreOverlap AS b ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.starttime NOT BETWEEN b.starttime AND b.endtime
  GROUP BY a.userid
order by userid, starttime, endtime
```

Comment: If we add another observation (1, 20110203, '10:04:00', '10:35:00'), then the result is wrong.

Comment: Oh, OK. However , reworked the query, but you already found a solution.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your help. I really love your solution, It is very smart. Thanks again for your smart solution. If you dont mind, please share your solution. I do love the method you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you say overlapping time, you are saying within the same hour on the same day. If that is what you mean, following solution might work. Attached is the screenshot of my results.[image: Result of Overlapping Dates problem]

```
CREATE TABLE #OverlappingDates
    (
      UserID INT
    , [date] DATE
    , starttime VARCHAR(5)
    , endtime VARCHAR(5)
    );

INSERT  INTO #OverlappingDates
        ( UserID, date, starttime, endtime )
VALUES  ( 1  -- UserID - int
          , '20110203'  -- date - date
          , '09:30'  -- starttime - time
          , '09:35'  -- endtime - time
          ),
        ( 1  -- UserID - int
          , '20110203'  -- date - date
          , '09:31'  -- starttime - time
          , '09:38'  -- endtime - time
          ),
        ( 1  -- UserID - int
          , '20110203'  -- date - date
          , '10:03'  -- starttime - time
          , '10:05'  -- endtime - time
          ),
        ( 2  -- UserID - int
          , '20110203'  -- date - date
          , '11:02'  -- starttime - time
          , '11:05'  -- endtime - time
          ),
        ( 2  -- UserID - int
          , '20110203'  -- date - date
          , '11:05'  -- starttime - time
          , '11:15'  -- endtime - time
          ),
        ( 2  -- UserID - int
          , '20110203'  -- date - date
          , '11:05'  -- starttime - time
          , '12:00'  -- endtime - time
          );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   UserID
                      , date
                      , MIN(starttime) AS StartTime
                      , MAX(endtime) AS EndTime
               FROM     #OverlappingDates
               GROUP BY UserID
                      , date
                      , LEFT(starttime, 2)
                      , LEFT(endtime, 2)
             )
    SELECT  cte.UserID
          , cte.date
          , cte.StartTime
          , cte.EndTime
          , ( RIGHT('0'
                    + CAST(( DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                                      ( CAST(CONCAT(( CAST(cte.[date] AS VARCHAR(10)) ),
                                                    ' ', cte.StartTime) AS DATETIME) ),
                                      ( CAST(CONCAT(( CAST(cte.[date] AS VARCHAR(10)) ),
                                                    ' ', cte.EndTime) AS DATETIME) )) )
                    / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0'
                                                          + CAST(( ( DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                                                          ( CAST(CONCAT(( CAST(cte.[date] AS VARCHAR(10)) ),
                                                          ' ',
                                                          cte.StartTime) AS DATETIME) ),
                                                          ( CAST(CONCAT(( CAST(cte.[date] AS VARCHAR(10)) ),
                                                          ' ', cte.EndTime) AS DATETIME) )) )
                                                          / 60 ) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),
                                                          2) ) AS Diff
    FROM    cte;
```

Comment: Actually no. Overlapping time means whether there are two record share the same or part of the same time period. For example, 9:01-9:05 is partially overlapped with 9:02-9:20. In this case, i treat it as one record, and calculate the duration as 9:20-9:01.  But 9:01-9:05 is not overlapping with 9:20-9:21.  In this case, i treat these two record as independent record.